# pythonic way to convert character position to terminal offset as printed

Tags: python-3.x

I am wondering if there is a "pythonic" way to from the a character position in a string to the terminal offset that character will be printed at (i.e including tabs).

For example take the following three strings:

```
$> python3
>>> print("+\tabc")
+   abc
>>> print("\tabc")
    abc
>>> print("    abc")
    abc
```

They are three difference strings, with three different character counts preceding the "abc", but the position of 'a' is different each time.

The only solution I have that works "well enough" is

```
def get_offset(s, c):
    pos = s.find(c)
    if pos == -1:
        return -1
    tablen = 0
    ntabs = 0
    for i in range(0, pos):
        if line[i] == '\t':
            tablen += (TABLEN - (i % TABLEN))
            ntabs += 1

    offset = tablen + (pos - ntabs)
    return offset
```

I am wondering is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

Because python doesn't know about how its output will be rendered, it cannot tell you the offset resulting from tab characters.  From python's point of view, a tab is a character like any other.